# How to ensure the access speed of an app backend from global visitor

Tags: ios, database, architecture, backend

Hi I just wondering how to ensure the access speed of an app backend from global visitor.
I wish to ensure the speed of getting data/file/img from server should be relatively fast in most of places. I understand the CDN may be a possible way, yet I do not think it could sync database as well.